# How to make responsive HTML buttons and position them together on small resolutions

Tags: html, css, responsive

In my website in the same `<div>`, I have a `<span>` with three buttons. This is how it looks like in front-end:

This is my HTML:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 noPadding" style="padding-bottom:15px;">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 noPadding">
        <span id="horaPantalla"></span>
        <i class="fa fa-cogs imgButton" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-camera imgButton" aria-hidden="true" id="configScan"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-sign-out imgButton" aria-hidden="true""></i>
     </div> 
</div>
```

If I access from my mobile phone I got this:

[image]

Two buttons are on the first line and then the other button is on the second line.

My goal is to fit all three buttons together, if the resolution is small I want to put all three buttons in a new row below the `<span>`.

I have tried the below by adding a class called resolution to the `<i>` elements:

```
.imgButton {
    font-size: 36px !important;
    /*padding: 2px;*/
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    cursor:pointer;
    background-color:#A3D1D4 !important;
    border:none !important;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
  .resolution {
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

This is what I get:

[image]

How can I put three `<i>` elements inline below the `<span>` on mobile devices?

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the three `i` elements in a container `div` and working from there?

Comment: @JacobLockard If wrapp the three elements in a container automatically it appears below the span with big resolution.  With big resolutions the three elements have to be on the right of the span.

Comment: You can make both the container and the date box `display: inline-block` and it should work. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap the icons in a container `div` and make both the `#hourPantella` span and the container div `display: inline-block`.

For example:

```css
.icon {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  
  display: inline-block;
}

.date, .icon-container {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="date">Date - Time</div>
<div class="icon-container">
  <div class="icon"></div>
  <div class="icon"></div>
  <div class="icon"></div>
</div>
```

And a JSFiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/5a8o7ykd/.

Note that this example is not exactly like what you showed. I just used placeholder divs instead of actual icons and I didn't actually put a date into the span. You should be able to adapt it to work with your code though.

Answer (score 0):

Check if this is what you want?

```css
@media (max-width: 900px) { 
  .block {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 noPadding">
    <span id="horaPantalla" class="block">Hour</span>
    <i class="fa fa-cogs imgButton" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-camera imgButton" aria-hidden="true" id="configScan"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: I have tried your solution and the span isn't shown.

Comment: On mobile device?

Comment: Sorry my fault. I missed the tag class. Yes on mobile device I can see the span, but the first button apears to the right of the span, and then the others buttons appear in a new row below the span